# material-ui DropDown with imag on selected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i am trying to use an image in my dropdown of material-ui of version 0.19.1 for achieving that i writes this code.

```
<DropDownMenu
    autoWidth
     style={{ width: 500, marginBottom: 30 }}
     underlineStyle={{ marginLeft: -1 }}
     menuItemStyle={{ width: 500 }}
     value={this.state.value}
     onChange={this.handleChange}>
     {items.map((item, i) => (
     <MenuItem
     value={i}
     key={item}
     leftIcon={<Avatar image={i} src={item.image} />}
     primaryText={item.label}
   />))}
```

but this works good when i click on dropdown for selection of some menuitem but when i select some menuitem image is not shows with selected it only shows label of dropdown.
thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

Check the "Label example" in the docs (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu)

You must add a label in the MenuItem